# What is the best way in objective C to work with array of float

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've got this simple method in java (a classic algorithm for random select with ponderation)

```
    public int roueDeLaFortune (Hashtable<Integer,Float> tab) {
        float l = 0 ;
        Integer i ;
        for(i=0;i<tab.size();i++) {
            l+=tab.get(i);
        }
        float bing = ((float) Math.random()*l);
        l = 0 ;
        for(i=0;i<tab.size();i++) {
            l+=tab.get(i);
            if(l>=bing) {
                return i ;
            }
        }
        return -1 ;
    }
```

My question: I'd like to write it on objective C, I'd like to consider what is the simple way (no speed consideration, only simple code) to use instead of Hashtable , when you need to work on an indexed array of floats.

Thx you for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of Java's `HashTable` in Objective-C is `NSDictionary`. You can't however store primitive types (like `float`) in a collection class (like `NSDictionary`) - Objective-C doesn't perform [boxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_%28computer_science%29#Boxing) automatically. You have to convert a float to an object of `NSNumber` class in order to store it in the collection, the most convenient way to do that is to use [Objective-C literals](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/):

```
NSDictionary* tab = @{ @1: @3.14f, @2: @0.7f };
```

I think that for your example (`roueDeLaFortune` method) NSArray would be more suitable, as it can be an "indexed array of floats":

```
NSArray* tab = @[ @3.14f, @0.7f ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C collections can only contain objects, so you can't put floats directly into them.

However, you can convert your floats to `NSNumber`s which you can put in an array, and then you have an indexed collection of numbers.

Comment: To create an NSNumber, you can simply write: "@(4.5f)" instead of "[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 4.5f]". The compiler will then alloc-ing an NSNumber, and you will have much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare:

```
Hashtable<Integer,Float> tab
```

Those 'Integer' And 'Float' are also objects and java automatically converts basic types to Integer and Float objects when you add them to the hash table.

In Objective-C NSNumber is the object that holds all number basic types so your HashTable would be a NSDictionary with NSNumber as keys (holding your integers) and another NSNumber as objects (holding your floats)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNumber or consider using Core Foundation CFArray or consider NSPointerArray